# How to get latitude and longitude in background service?

Tags: flutter, dart

As in the question. How to track location in background service in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `geolocator: ^4.0.3`
2. import `'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';`
3. Add permissions for android & ios
4. Use the below code

   ```
   void getLocation() async {
   Position position = await Geolocator()
       .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
   print(position);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin, you only need one line of code!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) is the offical Link with plugin and whole code.